# Error: "Cannot find module 'lowdb/node'" in Cypress

Tags: node.js, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, tree-shaking

I'm working on a Cypress test suite and I'm trying to load a component that uses the 'lowdb' package. However I'm encountering the following error: [cypress error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDoU9.png)

Cypress version: v13.6.0
Node.js version: v18.16.1
Windows

Any insight or suggestions on resolving this issue would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: please provide the error in text ,read [why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) and [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.